# Should File Server / 3rd Party Softwares / IIS be installed on separate VMs?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, file-server, hyper-v-server-2012-r2

I'm preparing for my mcsa 70-410 and managing our new server (Windows Server 2012 R2).

We are a network of 125 users. I wanted to know if it would be alright to host **File server + IIS roles and install 3rd party ERP applications on it??**

Will there be any security concerns? Should I host them on a single VM?

**Server Details :**
Dell Power Edge t430

3 x 2TB hard disks

2 disks on raid 1

1 disk = Hotspare

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

While there aren't any specific vulnerabilities that come from running a single server with multiple roles, it is highly discouraged. Best practice would be to separate out the components on their own machines where possible. Your systems are a bit more tolerant of failure when they are distributed that way, and you also have a smaller attack surface on each machine.

Comment: Out of our budget to have separate machines. I forgot to mention this server is the domain controller. So would it be safer , in terms of performance and security, to have the IIS and File server installed on a Hyper-V VM ?

Comment: Security-wise, yes that would be better. As for performance... you'd probably get better performance without hyper-v, but I think the security benefits outweigh the overhead of virtualization.